# Как отслеживать изменения в DB MS SQL 2008 на C# через Service Broker?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Никак не могу разобраться с вопросом отслеживания изменений в базе данных.

Имеется:

- Приложение, написанное на C#
- SQL Server, с базой данной на 3 таблички

В программе делаю следующее:

```
public Main_Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
    ScoutingSQL();

    DataGridView_Load();
}

//  создаем dependency и подписываем его на событие
// которое должно вызвать Service Broker 
private void ScoutingSQL()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT sentDate, verificationDate, verifiedTo", connection);
    SqlDependecy dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
}

// метод, вызванный событием
void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView_Load();
}

// Загружаем данные из sql бд в наш грид
public void DataGridView_Load()
{
    while(dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
       for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows[i]);
       {
           dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[i]);
       }
    string tableName = "[staff_106].[dbo].[staff]"
    string querry = ("SELECT * FROM" + tableName + "");
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(querry, connection);
    // и тд... просто делаем  Fill из dataSet, заполняя грид.
}
```

Кусок для SqlDependency писал по [этому примеру](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency)

В самой бд сделал `ALTER DATABASE [Database_name] SET ENABLE_BROKER;`

Но... по какой-то причине, по ПКМ->Свойства->Отслеживание изменений в поле Отслеживание изменений висело False. Ну, ручками переключил на True.

Запускаю приложение, меняю что-то в бд через SQL SMS и... ничего не происходит. Проверял брейкпоинтом, по событию даже не вызывается метод.

У меня появилось ряд вопросов, в ходе изучения матчасти.

1) Queue. Как узнать имя моей очереди по дефолту. Как её конфигурировать? Потому что, как я понял, у меня не совсем полный код для SqlDependency, т.к. требуется

```
SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, queueName);
```

но queueName я не знаю.

2) Мне нужно только узнавать о том, были изменения или нет. Какие конкретно, мне не важно, и непонятно для чего в примере висит этот кусок:

```
// Execute the command.  
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())  
    {  
        // Process the DataReader.  
    }
```

Точнее как, понятно, что по идее по правильному я должен подтянуть те самые изменения из Queue и уже дальше работать с ними, к примеру, ими заполнить ячейку в  гриде, а не заполнять заново весь грид (но он у меня мелкий и особо я не теряю от Fill), но, вероятно, это что-то нужное, раз у меня не влзелето?

3) Как в SQL SMS проверить работает ли вообще Service Broker? Я читал про сообщения в бд, на которые должен, якобы, ответить Service Broker, но конкретного ничего не вычитал (что он должен ответить, в какой форме, куда, как смотреть этот пакет в таком случае).

Я понимаю, что вопросы крайне глупые, и надеюсь на ваше терпение.
Благодарю за любую помощь и пояснения по моему вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Намучался в своё время с сервис-брокером, вот этот код работает (естественно на стороне БД всё тоже должно быть правильно настроено):

```
public class ServiceBrokerWatcher
{
    public ServiceBrokerWatcher(string conn, string query)
    {
        dependencyQuery = query;
        connectionString = conn;
        StartWatching(conn);
        ExecuteWatchingQuery();
    }

    private readonly string dependencyQuery;
    private readonly string connectionString;
    public event EventHandler ContextChangedEvent;
    private SqlDependency sqlDependency;

    public static void StartWatching(string connectionString)
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
    }

    private void ExecuteWatchingQuery()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(dependencyQuery, connection))
            {
                sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                sqlDependency.OnChange += OnDatabaseChange;
                command.Execute();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDatabaseChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (sqlDependency != null)
            {
                sqlDependency.OnChange -= OnDatabaseChange;
            }
            ExecuteWatchingQuery();

            SqlNotificationInfo info = args.Info;

            if (SqlNotificationInfo.Insert.Equals(info)
                || SqlNotificationInfo.Update.Equals(info)
                || SqlNotificationInfo.Delete.Equals(info))
            {
                AppLogger.Logger.Debug("Обновление данных!");

                if (ContextChangedEvent != null)
                {
                    ContextChangedEvent(this, new EventArgs());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.AppLogger.Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Использовать примерно так:

```
    internal void ServiceBrokerWatcherInit()
    {
        updateWatcher = new ServiceBrokerWatcher(MainForm.DBConnectString, @"select id from dbo.ProductHistory");
        updateWatcher.ContextChangedEvent += updateWatcher_ContextChangedEvent;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
А что, кроме как включения брокера, должно быть настроено на стороне сервера?

Comment: Вот тут описано включение брокера на стороне БД https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexejs/2009/08/15/183/

И по коду, его логика такова - следим за таблицей dbo.ProductHistory - как только в ней появляется запись, сервис-брокер шлет оповещение, его получает код C# дергает событие, а в его обработчике можно делать что угодно.

Comment: ту статью читал, спасибо за вашу помощь!